# How to find the derivative with respect to $x$ of $3x^2 + 2$ from first principle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

I just started differentiation and the example solved/explained is different from the question asked during exercise:

> How do you solve or find the derivative with respect to $x$ of $3x^{3} + 2$?

Comment: Your textbook has the right idea. Did you try computing $f(x + \Delta x)$ and expanding it out?

Comment: This not a 'do my homework site'. Please show your work also.

Comment: Also the image shows a different function than what you copied

Comment: @Surb is right!   You want $f(x)=3x^3 +2$

Comment: $f(x+\Delta x) = 3(x+\Delta x)^3 +2$.   $\quad \quad$  Now compute $\frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$.   $\quad \quad$ You will also need $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + \cdots.$

Comment: So, show us your work.  To start, following the sample, but using $f(x) = 3x^3+2$, compute $f(x)$ and then compute $f(x+\Delta x)$.  Show us that in your question.

Comment: will work on that! @GEdgar

Comment: Yep it worked!  

Comment: https://z-m-scontent.flos5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/fr/cp0/e15/q65/210580663_1495290797513125_9087105006085387493_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=110474&efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&_nc_eui2=AeHbKdOT-LbDh6_GdKvVSJh7NRUU71IAFNg1FRTvUgAU2EXy1byX8YkKNEpkzjv3TSm8FpxX5k8acjxCk1cewW9x&_nc_ohc=wH7LNJAcdP8AX-gSeTY&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=1080&_nc_eh=dfa489df0cc797e3731dd67f65572076&_nc_rml=0&_nc_ht=z-m-scontent.flos5-1.fna&tp=14&oh=8aea864d93b32f5df8922b9a00397cf5&oe=60E4E819

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the solution that the asker came up with, with help from the comments (so that it's written and formatted, not in a Facebook image):

$3x^3 + 2$ from first principles.
$$f(x) = 3x^3 + 2$$
If $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$,
\begin{align*}
f(x + \Delta x) &= 3(x + \Delta x)^3 + 2 \\
&=3[(x + \Delta x)(x + \Delta x)(x + \Delta x)] + 2 \\
&= 3[(x^2 + x \Delta x + x \Delta x + \Delta x^2)(x + \Delta x)] + 2 \\
&= 3[x^3 + x^2 \Delta x + 2x^2 \Delta x + 2x \Delta x^2 + x \Delta x^2 + \Delta x^3] + 2 \\
&= 3[x^3 + 3x^2 \Delta x + 3x \Delta x^2 + \Delta x^3] + 2 \\
&= 3x^3 + 9x^2 \Delta x + 9x \Delta x^2 + 3\Delta x^3 + 2 \\
f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) &= [3 x^3 + 9x^2 \Delta x + 9x \Delta x^2 + 3\Delta x^3 + 2] - (3x^3 + 2) \\
&= 3 x^3 + 9x^2 \Delta x + 9x \Delta x^2 + 3\Delta x^3 + 2 - 3x^3 - 2 \\
&= 9x^2 \Delta x + 9x \Delta x^2 + 3\Delta x^3 \\
\frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} &= 9x^2 + 9x \Delta x + 3\Delta x^2 \\
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} &= 9x^2 + 0 + 0 = 9x^2.
\end{align*}